# Cascading dropdown lookup field: display name, send id to the database

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

In cascading dropdown i want to display name in the form and send id to the database. Both display name and id are stored in list (measuringPointParam). Can someone help mе with that.

In servlet:

```
int mpCode = 0;
String mpCodeStr = request.getParameter("mpCode");
if (mpCodeStr != null && !mpCodeStr.equals("")) {
    mpCode = Integer.parseInt(mpCodeStr);
}

List < MeasuringPoint > measuringPoints = measuringPointManager.list();
request.setAttribute("measuringPoints", measuringPoints);

List < MeasuringPointParam > measuringPointParams = measuringPointParamManager.list(mpCode);
request.setAttribute("measuringPointParams", measuringPointParams);

for (MeasuringPointParam mpp: measuringPointParams) {
    measuringPointParams.add(mpp);
}

String json = new Gson().toJson(measuringPointParams);

response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(json);
}
```

In JSP:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#measuringPointCode').change(function(event) {
            var measuringPointCode = $("select#measuringPointCode").val();
     $.ajax({
         url : 'LogParamDropdown',
         data : {mpCode : measuringPointCode},
         type : 'GET',
         dataType : 'json',
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         success: function (jsonResponse) { 
             var select = $('#measuringPointParamCode');  
                select.find('option').remove();
                $.each(jsonResponse, function(index, value) {
                    $('<option>').val(value).text(value).appendTo(select);
                });
         },
         error: function () { 
         alert ("Failed to load data");
         }
          });
        });
      });        


 </script>
```

....

```
<div>
   <label for="measuringPointCode">
      <fmt:message key="measuringPoint"/>
      :
   </label>
   <select class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" name="measuringPointCode" id="measuringPointCode" >
      <option>
         <fmt:message key="logParam.measuringPoints"/>
      </option>
      <c:forEach items="${measuringPoints}" var="measuringPoint">
         <option value="${measuringPoint.measuringPointCode}" ${measuringPoint.measuringPointCode == logParam.measuringPointParam.measuringPoint.measuringPointCode ? 'selected' : ''}>${measuringPoint.measuringPointName}</option>
      </c:forEach>
   </select>
</div>
<div>
   <label for="measuringPointParamCode">
      <fmt:message key="energyParam"/>
      :
   </label>
   <select class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" name="measuringPointParamCode" id="measuringPointParamCode" required>
      <option>
         <fmt:message key="logParam.energyParams"/>
      </option>
      <!-- must send measuringPointParamCode to the base , now sending energyParamName-->
   </select>
</div>
```